# top: sy higher than 70: What is going on here?

Tags: linux, performance, high-load

From the man page of `top`:

> sy: time running kernel processes

The sy-value has peaks with values above 50, and then goes down to about 5 again.

What could be the root of it?

Here are two snapshots of `top` and the output of `vmstat 1 5`

## top

Sy-value 72.2:

```
top - 15:05:31 up 73 days,  1:41,  4 users,  load average: 5,64, 4,89, 4,36
Tasks: 222 total,  23 running, 199 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,1 us,  *74,9 sy*,  0,0 ni, 13,7 id, 11,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:  20492080 total, 19555680 used,   936400 free,  3243624 buffers
KiB Swap:  2095100 total,  1770960 used,   324140 free, 14142880 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                    
14292 wwwrun    20   0  124m 6136 1332 R  78,0  0,0   0:02.49 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
14293 wwwrun    20   0  124m 6136 1332 R  75,7  0,0   0:02.30 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
 9121 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  67,1  0,0   0:05.86 kworker/8:0                                                                                                                                                                
12477 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  56,8  0,0   0:05.69 kworker/0:2                                                                                                                                                                
14296 postgres  20   0 7226m 1112  664 R  31,4  0,0   0:00.95 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
14285 postgres  20   0 7233m 7344 5564 S  24,1  0,0   0:01.91 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
   49 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S  23,8  0,0  32:26.38 migration/8                                                                                                                                                                
26159 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  23,8  0,0   0:35.23 kworker/10:0                                                                                                                                                               
10590 modcron   30  10 84372 8384 1380 S  19,8  0,0   3:06.98 modcron-cmd.py                                                                                                                                                             
14291 postgres  20   0 7233m 5036 3528 R  19,2  0,0   0:00.74 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
 1829 postgres  20   0 7225m  16m  16m S  13,5  0,1   9:41.58 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
24583 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  13,2  0,0   1:21.04 kworker/2:0                                                                                                                                                                
13582 modwork+  39  19  313m  99m 7740 S  12,6  0,5   0:25.06 archiviere_bele                                                                                                                                                            
 1760 rabbitmq  20   0 2886m  36m 2024 S  10,9  0,2   1118:14 beam.smp                                                                                                                                                                   
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 R  10,6  0,0 116:55.84 migration/0                                                                                                                                                                
14289 modwork+  39  19 42116 3688 2464 R  10,2  0,0   0:00.99 ssh                                                                                                                                                                        
   12 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   9,3  0,0  17:01.30 watchdog/1                                                                                                                                                                 
32089 root      20   0  135m  33m 1292 R   8,6  0,2  13:46.11 rsync                                                                                                                                                                      
28100 modwork+  20   0  698m 159m  16m S   7,9  0,8   1:51.36 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
   48 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   6,6  0,0   7:01.48 ksoftirqd/8                                                                                                                                                                
  288 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   6,3  0,0   1:57.83 flush-253:0                                                                                                                                                                
 1828 postgres  20   0 7225m  82m  81m S   5,9  0,4   2:36.61 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
   47 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   5,6  0,0  15:33.23 watchdog/8                                                                                                                                                                 
 1415 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   4,0  0,0   0:39.58 kworker/4:0                                                                                                                                                                
14287 postgres  20   0 7233m 5052 3544 R   4,0  0,0   0:01.01 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
13967 postgres  20   0 7273m 271m 233m R   3,6  1,4   0:39.91 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
 5856 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   3,0  0,0   0:09.37 kworker/1:1                                                                                                                                                                
19049 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   2,3  0,0   0:25.17 kworker/3:1                                                                                                                                                                
 1494 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   2,0  0,0   5:56.14 flush-253:16                                                                                                                                                               
  478 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   1,7  0,0   9:09.84 jbd2/vdb1-8                                                                                                                                                                
17830 modwork+  20   0  268m  20m 6912 S   1,3  0,1  52:06.14 celery                                                                                                                                                                     
17861 root      20   0  123m 7116 4024 S   1,0  0,0   5:39.92 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,3  0,0  52:22.43 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                                
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,3  0,0  83:14.45 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                                  
  203 root       0 -20     0    0    0 R   0,3  0,0  67:48.68 kworker/0:1H                                                                                                                                                               
  509 root      20   0  7304 1264  660 S   0,3  0,0  18:06.80 haveged                                                                                                                                                                    
13529 modwork+  20   0 19520 1844 1196 R   0,3  0,0   0:00.71 top
```

Sy-value 41.2:

```
top - 15:09:09 up 73 days,  1:45,  4 users,  load average: 3,03, 3,98, 4,12
Tasks: 221 total,   6 running, 214 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,2 us, *41,2 sy*,  0,1 ni, 51,7 id,  6,5 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2 si,  0,1 st
KiB Mem:  20492080 total, 19548000 used,   944080 free,  3257416 buffers
KiB Swap:  2095100 total,  1771524 used,   323576 free, 14183352 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                    
15716 modwork+  39  19 85704  20m 2324 R  86,6  0,1   0:04.08 convert                                                                                                                                                                    
   14 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S  68,8  0,0  51:04.96 migration/1                                                                                                                                                                
   49 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S  62,9  0,0  32:29.92 migration/8                                                                                                                                                                
14364 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  61,3  0,0   0:06.00 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                                                                
15719 modcron   30  10 36900 5444 2332 R  60,3  0,0   0:01.86 check_load                                                                                                                                                                 
10590 modcron   30  10 84372 8384 1380 S  37,3  0,0   3:09.08 modcron-cmd.py                                                                                                                                                             
15718 postgres  20   0 7233m 7600 5792 R  30,8  0,0   0:01.68 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
15717 postgres  20   0 7233m 9764 7480 S  17,5  0,0   0:01.92 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
   19 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S  16,5  0,0  57:53.36 migration/2                                                                                                                                                                
30709 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  13,9  0,0   0:11.11 kworker/5:0                                                                                                                                                                
19049 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  13,3  0,0   0:25.90 kworker/3:1                                                                                                                                                                
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 R  13,0  0,0 117:09.89 migration/0                                                                                                                                                                
   17 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S  10,4  0,0  15:07.58 watchdog/2                                                                                                                                                                 
 1519 ntp       20   0 27092 1616 1388 S   6,8  0,0   6:47.32 ntpd                                                                                                                                                                       
 1415 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   5,2  0,0   0:41.00 kworker/4:0                                                                                                                                                                
 1524 rabbitmq  20   0  7344  316  316 S   5,2  0,0   1:08.64 epmd                                                                                                                                                                       
32089 root      20   0  135m  35m 1292 D   5,2  0,2  15:05.85 rsync                                                                                                                                                                      
15026 wwwrun    20   0     0    0    0 Z   4,2  0,0   0:00.17 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
26159 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   4,2  0,0   0:36.43 kworker/10:0                                                                                                                                                               
27992 modwork+  20   0  698m 151m  16m S   4,2  0,8   1:57.30 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
  478 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   3,2  0,0   9:10.07 jbd2/vdb1-8                                                                                                                                                                
15432 modwork+  20   0 19392 1792 1184 R   3,2  0,0   0:00.20 top                                                                                                                                                                        
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   2,3  0,0  13:07.37 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                                                
  203 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   1,9  0,0  67:51.00 kworker/0:1H                                                                                                                                                               
   33 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,6  0,0   7:56.53 ksoftirqd/5                                                                                                                                                                
   48 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,6  0,0   7:01.55 ksoftirqd/8                                                                                                                                                                
  509 root      20   0  7304 1264  660 S   0,6  0,0  18:07.12 haveged                                                                                                                                                                    
 1760 rabbitmq  20   0 2886m  36m 2024 S   0,6  0,2   1118:17 beam.smp                                                                                                                                                                   
 1826 postgres  20   0 7226m 3,3g 3,3g D   0,6 16,7  32:19.05 postgres                                                                                                                                                                   
27950 modwork+  20   0  699m 159m  16m S   0,6  0,8   2:17.94 httpd2-prefork                                                                                                                                                             
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,3  0,0  52:22.69 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                                
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,3  0,0  83:16.95 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                                  
 1453 modwork+  20   0  223m  16m 5228 S   0,3  0,1  79:09.48 celery                                                                                                                                                                     
17830 modwork+  20   0  268m  20m 6912 S   0,3  0,1  52:08.47 celery                                                                                                                                                                     
    1 root      20   0 45752 2964 1804 S   0,0  0,0   5:47.74 systemd
```

## vmstat

vmstat output:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
29  1 1786384 550668 3326544 14359188    0    0    22    11    0    0  2  1 97  0  0
35  0 1786384 558988 3323304 14355956    0    0    72    60 3134 1542  3 97  0  0  0
29  0 1786384 556404 3323300 14354380    0    0     8     0 3580 1066  1 99  0  0  0
19  1 1786384 579688 3323528 14340016    0    0   228    28 4495 5194  4 90  4  2  0
22  1 1786384 559376 3323724 14338364    0    0   188   252 3240 2890  9 85  4  2  0
```

I read it like this: the system is **not** swapping.

## Linux version

```
foo-work:~ # uname -a
Linux foo-work.example.com 3.7.10-1.45-default #1 SMP 
Tue Dec 16 20:27:58 UTC 2014 (4c885a1) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Reasons for high sy?

Here are some reasons I know why sy could be high in general. All don't apply to my situation.

### Spawning a lot of new processes

Up to now I have only seen high sy-value if shell scripts start several new processes per second like grep, cut, sed, ...

But on this system I think it is not the case.

### /dev/urandom

AFAIK no process reads it.

### ...

What is causing high `sy` here?

### Solution: Hypervisor with no RAM for himself.

I finally found the root of the problem. The host was a virtual machine running on kvm/qemu. Some sysadmin had added new virtual hosts to the hypervisor and did some foolish calculation: I have 32GByte RAM on the hypervisor, let's give the one machine 20GByte and the other 12GByte. Result: The hypervisor itself had not RAM left!

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong with this question before down-voting. I am will update the question if something is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misreading your tools.  Your one-minute-average system loads are 5.64 and 3.03 respectively (top line, right-hand end).  The 74.9 and 41.2 figures are the **percentage** of time the CPU spends servicing system requests, usually IO or memory.

Given that swap is being fairly heavily used, my guess would be memory.  You can get a better feel for that by running `vmstat` and/or `iostat`, to look for memory and IO usage, respectively.  I'd spend some time reading the `man` pages first, though, so you are clear on what each tool is telling you.

Given that you're using non-zero amounts of swap, I'd take a look and see if much of the core usage was FS cacheing, and if it wasn't, I'd **definitely** have more than 2GB of swap for a system with 20GB core.  Heavy memory load could blow through swap and into the OOM killer in next-to-no time.

Comment: According to the man page of `top`: "sy, system  : time running kernel processes" that is what my question is about. Why is this value high? I have not seen such high values before. The value 5.64 is the load.

Comment: I added vmstat output: I read it like this: the system is not swapping.

Comment: how can I see if "much of the core usage is FS cacheing"? Tell me a command line and I will post the output here.

Comment: @guettli until you edited it out of your own question, you described the 74.9 and 41.2 figures as, and I quote, "*system load*"; it's not a great idea to edit your own errors out, then take people to task for pointing them out.  I am sorry that you haven't seen systems with 70% of the CPU spent servicing system requests, but it's not uncommon; try running a couple of `tar` processes and watch that fraction soar (it's the IO).  This question is changing really rapidly; I suggest that you accept an answer, close this question out, and write a new one asking what you *now* want to know.

Comment: Yes there was a wording issue in the first version. That's why it was down-voted. I will open a new question.

Comment: Here is the new question: http://serverfault.com/questions/771866/top-sy-higher-than-70-what-is-going-on-here